# Сослаться на класс, который описан "ниже" в модуле Python

Tags: python

Есть пара классов:

```
class A:
    # b = B()
    pass


class B:
    a = A()
```

Как мне в классе **`A`** получить поле типа **`B`**?

Comment: Если только в рантайме - определить метод, который возвращает экземпляр класса `B`. Но вообще стоит этого избегать, циклических зависимостей быть не должно.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev Подскажите, как написать метод, который возвращает экземпляр класса?

Comment: Да вы, должно быть, шутите... `def get_b(self): return B()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
class A:
    pass

class B:
    a = A()

A.b = B()
```

Только имейте в виду, что `b` и `a` создаются один раз в процессе создания классов `A` и `B` (в случае `b` чуть позже создания класса), а не каждый раз при создании экземпляров соответствующих классов.

```py
b1 = B()
b2 = B()
print(b1.a is b2.a) # True
b1.a.x = 1
print(b2.a.x) # 1
```